# Monotouch - Twitter/Path Application Master-Detail Swipe Table View

Tags: xamarin.ios

Any clue on how to create the twitter ipad application or path application swipe master-detail table view effect using MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Our good friend Clancey has a C# port of what is called "FlyOutNavigation" on Github. It works on both iPhone and iPad. However he has a custom MonoTouch.Dialog project which is not included in the repo. So I created a custom DialogViewController implementation you can just drop in (see below).

Code: https://github.com/Clancey/FlyOutNavigation

Custom DialogViewController:

```
public class NavigationDvc : DialogViewController
{
    public Action<NSIndexPath> OnSelection { get; set; }

    public NavigationDvc(UITableViewStyle style, RootElement root)
        : base(style, root)
    {   
    }

    public override void Selected(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        base.Selected(indexPath);

        if(OnSelection != null) {
            OnSelection(indexPath); 
        }
    }
}
```